# Regex expression for parsing URLs my way

Tags: regex, url

I've a question in how to parse urls, my way.

Here's my regex expression:

```
[^\s]+?\.(com|net|org|edu...ALL_DOMAIN_EXTENSIONS)([^\s\w\d][^\s]{1,})?
```

My rationalle is that I want to accept

```
mail.google.com (as long as there's a .com, .net etc)
```

However the .com must be followed by a symbol (if any) and not alphanumeric. However in this way of checking, this url will fail

```
www.company.com
```

However I cant do a greedy repetiton to search for a .com as in this case

```
developer.google.com/appid=com.company.apppackage
```

How do I search to check for the first occurance of a '.com' without a alphanumeric character following it, yet making it optional in case its just

Google.com

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` as an alternative to match the end of the string.

```
[^\s]+?\.(com|net|org|edu...ALL_DOMAIN_EXTENSIONS)([^\s\w\d][^\s]+|$)?
```

BTW, trying to match all top-level domains will drive you crazy, since anyone can now register a TLD, so they change frequently.